# Threadedcomments - csrf token and user_name

Tags: django, django-comments

I am using django-threadedcomments. Everything works fine except 2 things: csrf token and user template tag.

Problem is, when user submits a comment, there is no csrf token for the form, so the form could not be validated server-side. Tried adding csrf token to the dictionaries that threaded-comments passes internal with no result; kept receiving errors (most of them telling that this-method takes only 2 arguments with 3 given). Tried to fix those methods to accept 3 arguments and just pass third one further; no success.

Did someone stumble upon the same problem in past and solved it? because this is not an acceptable solution for me:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

Second one - there is a HTML helper to get the user_id for the user who posted a comment. Is there an out of the box html helper to get the name of the user by id or would i have to write it myself?

http://code.google.com/p/django-threadedcomments/

Here is the code for the project, I cant really tell exactly which chunks of it should be posted here so I just give link to the entire project.

I am really stuck in here and any help would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you "show" the comment form ? do you include in the view response or by using the templatetag?

Comment: Ok, so probably you need to hack threadedcomments's template_tags code in order to render the csrf_token inside the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tried adding csrf token to the
>   dictionaries that threaded-comments
>   passes internal with no result;

`csrf_token` is a template tag -- it shouldn't be passed as an argument somewhere.

I took a look at `threadedcomments` and it's based on `contrib.comments` with no html rendering, so it's up to you to insert the `csrf_token` in your template.

What does your TEMPLATE code look like that is displaying your form code?

If you have `CsrfViewMiddleware` enabled and you are using `RequestContext` in your view, you simply need to add `{% csrf_token %}` inside of your `<form></form>` tags.

**As for getting the user name**:
`ThreadedComment` is a subclasses of `Comment` which has a `name` property, or you could just access the `User` directly...

```
{% for comment in comments % 
    {{ comment.user.first_name }}
    {{ comment.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `{% csrf_token %}` tag or `@csrf_protect` in a views

Comment: Whenever a {% csrf_token %} tag is used it should be provided by the view that was called, problem is: Tried adding csrf token to the dictionaries that threaded-comments passes internal with no result; kept receiving errors (most of them telling that this-method takes only 2 arguments with 3 given). Tried to fix those methods to accept 3 arguments and just pass third one further; no success.

Comment: did you try to use decorator method?

Comment: btw: why you dont want to use CsrfViewMiddleWare?

Comment: Yes - it ignores it completely doing nothing. And when i submit the form it gives a 403 csrf error.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to pass context? context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: Told in the description of my problem that if I try to i get error. Thats the point - I don't know how to fix that issue. That what I've asked in first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can put your form in its own template and `{% include %}` it into your page template.  As of Django 1.3, `{% include %}` can pass context variables to the included template.  Here's what I'm using with `django.contrib.comments` instead of a templatetag:

```
...
{% include "comments/comment-form.html" with content_object=article user=request.user %}
...
```

`{%csrf_token %}` works in this included template because it's using your main view context.